# Make (custom) post type accessible only by custom query

Tags: custom-post-types, query, user-access

I am trying to make a web application based on wordpress.
This application needs some text data to process and then display to users. For that I use a custom post type. So far so good.

Problem is, I do not want the data (some posts) to be accessible by normal way, but only by my custom queries which process them. I do not want users to have any chance of seeing that data. Is there any way to disable post form being read by default loop and allow only my own queries?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `'publicly_queryable' => false` when [registering](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) your CPT.